# Custom attributes in style

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, custom-attributes, android-custom-attributes

In my current project styles.xml I try to define:

```
<resources xmlns:ripple="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<resources xmlns:ripple="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.gorkem.components">
```

and I use this:

```
<style name="FlatTextRipple">
    <item name="ripple:rv_centered">true</item>
    <item name="ripple:rv_color">#CCCCCC</item>
    <item name="ripple:rv_type">simpleRipple</item>
    <item name="ripple:rv_zoom">true</item>
    <item name="ripple:rv_zoomDuration">300</item>

</style>
```

and in my library project I have attrs.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="RippleView">
    <attr name="rv_alpha" format="integer" />
    <attr name="rv_framerate" format="integer" />
    <attr name="rv_rippleDuration" format="integer" />
    <attr name="rv_zoomDuration" format="integer" />
    <attr name="rv_color" format="color" />
    <attr name="rv_centered" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="rv_type" format="enum">
        <enum name="simpleRipple" value="0" />
        <enum name="doubleRipple" value="1" />
        <enum name="rectangle" value="2" />
    </attr>
    <attr name="rv_ripplePadding" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="rv_zoom" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="rv_zoomScale" format="float" />
</declare-styleable>
```

But I don't understand when Í use it like in layout it is running but when I use style.xml gradle can not attr and it gives me this error :

```
    Error:(6, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'ripple:rv_centered'.
    Error:(7, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'ripple:rv_color'.
    Error:(8, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'ripple:rv_type'.
    Error:(9, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'ripple:rv_zoom'.
```

Comment: you wrote *<resoources ...>* with double "O"

Comment: i wrote here wrong in my code it is correct

Answer (score 7):

Styles don't match what you do in layouts. In your `styles.xml`, remove your custom `xmlns` declaration, and just use the attributes directly with no prefix, like so:

```
<style name="FlatTextRipple">
    <item name="rv_centered">true</item>
    <item name="rv_color">#CCCCCC</item>
    <item name="rv_type">simpleRipple</item>
    <item name="rv_zoom">true</item>
    <item name="rv_zoomDuration">300</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Worked for me. API 23.